# Is there a single event type for ddl trigger that tracks all drop events in database (t-sql)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I want my trigger to log all drop events happening in my database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [log]
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_TABLE, DROP_FUNCTION, DROP_TRIGGER, ...
AS ...
```

Can I just replace all the drop events with one general for drop?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [log]
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_FOR_ALL_DATABASE_OBJECTS
AS ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS`. By this `event` you can log every events.

`evendata()` function includes every information you need to log. For example event type, object name and so on. Note that `eventdata()` returns `XML`.

```
create trigger [log]
on database
for DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
as
begin

    declare
        @eventType  as sysname;

    select
        @eventType  = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'SYSNAME');

    if @eventType like '%drop%'
        ...

end;
```

**UPDATE:**

`eventdate()` XML sample result:

```
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>**</EventType>
  <PostTime>**</PostTime>
  <SPID>**</SPID>
  <ServerName>**</ServerName>
  <LoginName>**</LoginName>
  <UserName>**</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>**</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName />
  <ObjectName>**</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>**</ObjectType>
  <TargetObjectName />
  <TargetObjectType>**</TargetObjectType>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>
        ...
    </CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```